# What exactly does 'sudo -su'?

Tags: linux, authentication, terminal

I have a linux user (user2) which has set as shell `/usr/sbin/nologin` (to block logins). No when I try to switch to this user with `sudo su user2` I get the info that this account is not available. But whe I user `sudo -su user` it works fine.

What is now the difference between `su` and `-su`. Or what does `-su`. I tried to get the help with `-h` or `--help` or the manpage but I coulnd not find anything helpfull.

Comment: The `-s` option means use the caller's shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo -su user` is short for `sudo -s -u user`.  The `-s` option means to run ***the shell specified in the environment variable `SHELL` if this has been set, or else the user's login shell***.  The `-u user` option means to run the command as the specified user rather than root.  These options are documented under `man sudo`.

`sudo su user` will use `sudo` to run the command `su user` as the root user.  The `su` command will then invoke ***the login shell of the specified username***.  The `su user` command could be run without the use of `sudo`, but by running it as root it will not require the password of the target user.  For more information see `man su`.

So the two commands look similar (largely coincidentally) and have a somewhat similar effect when the target user has the same login shell as that of the invoking user.  However, in the case that the `SHELL` environment variable is set in the invoking user's environment (which it usually is, and it is typically `/bin/bash`), and that the target user has a login shell which differs from this (such as `/usr/sbin/nologin`), there is then a difference between which shell gets executed by these two commands, and this is what you are seeing.